# Obj-C: EXC_BAD_ACCESS strange error with ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

So I have a `WebView` inside a custom `NSObject` subclass called `GoogleLinkFetcher` and what I do is load a request from the `webview` and in `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` I call self to call a method on it. If I don't call that method everything works fine, if I do an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error points to that line. I read something about `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` regarding deallocating and memory allocations but I'm in an ARC environment so I would expect not to have problems with that... Here is the code:

```
-(void)searchLinks
{
    NSLog(@"searching links at googlelinksearcher url: %@", googleUrl);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:googleUrl];
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
    [webView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
}

-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    if(frame == sender.mainFrame)
    {
        NSLog(@"main frame");
        [self getLinks];
    }
}
```

The error points right to [self getLinks].

I hope somebody could help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be that you start the loading process but don't hold a strong reference to your `GoogleLinkFetcher` instance and it is released before the web view finishes loading (actually right after it starts).

Put a breakpoint in `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` method and check if `self` is still a valid instance of `GoogleLinkFetcher`. Or `NSLog` `self` before you call `getLinks`.

Comment: (Same idea here :-) But if self is nil then *nothing* would happen. I assume that self is *not* nil even if the instance has been deallocated. Perhaps setting a breakpoint or NSLog() in dealloc would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I tried putting a strong reference on my googleLinkFetcher property and I tried with NSLog and breakpoint and I get this error now: *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[__NSCFString getLinks]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101a10900...

Comment: And I overrided dealloc with NSLog and it appears to be called soon after the request which means the problem is there

Comment: Well, it tries to send a `getLinks` message to a string, so your GoogleLinkFetcher was probably released already at that point. Where do you hold the strong reference?

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, last comment made me realise I was holding googleLinkFetcher as a strong property but not the object that was holding it, saving that object in a property did the trick, thanks again! :)

Comment: @BigCola You're welcome. Btw, if you're just trying to download the HTML content of a specific site, you don't need a web view. You can use [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Oh yes thanks, but Google does a pretty good job hiding the effective html content so I opted for this solution :)